# NLTK Sent Tokenizer Throwing Errors Both on Centos and Windows

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

Following this tutorial here: http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-ii-sentence-tokenize-and-word-tokenize I was trying to tokenize a text file and got those errors:

This on centos 6.9

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentProc000.py", line 5, in <module>
    sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 88, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1226, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1274, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1265, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1304, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 311, in _pair_iter
    for el in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1280, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1325, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1460, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 577, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 542, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and this one on Windows 10:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 94, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 311, in _pair_iter
    for el in it:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1291, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1337, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1472, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 577, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 542, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Tried both manually using the python command line commands as explained in the tutorial, and running a py script based on that same tutorial.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

with open('1', 'r') as content_file:
    text = content_file.read()

sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)

thefile = open('result.txt', 'w')

for item in sent_tokenize_list:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Update: I managed to find out where the problem really resides. It's the `â€™` chars that in the UTF-8 are displayed as a single quote char. How can I solve this issue without having to manually edit all such chars?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed caused by decoding/encoding.

Here is the full working script:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

with open('1', 'r') as content_file:
    text = content_file.read()

text = text.decode('utf-8')

sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)

thefile = open('result.txt', 'w')

for item in sent_tokenize_list:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3 the default encoding is `utf8` already. If you're using Python 2 use the `io` library and do `with io.open('1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as content_file`; that way you won't need to do the `text.decoder('utf8') step. It's cleaner to just open the file with the right encoding from the start.